# Email Notifications Implementation - Web Application

Tags: django, email

Good day,

I'm having difficulty structuring how I should set up email notifications for a Django app that I built.

As I'm seeing an increase of users in the app, it increases the occurrence of email notifications being sent out. The app sends out email for every important event, examples are registration, confirmation, approved posts, etc.

My problem is, with Microsoft O365 as my email provider it sometimes block my email when reaching a certain limit. Therefore it stops all email notifications in the app.

Is there a better way to do this? Should I setup my own email server? There are times where I do mass emails too for announcements, I've tried using MailChimp but most email clients redirect them to Spam/Junk/Trash or other folders. I would rather prefer if emails end up on the Primary folder.

Thank you so much, looking forward to your suggestion/s and/or responses.

Comment: I would suggest investigating the issue with MailChimp, most likely they can do something about it

Comment: I second investigating with MailChimp.  You also need to ensure that you are following applicable regulations, such as CAN-SPAM in the US.

Answer (score 1):

I think using a third-party CRM for things like this is still definitely your best bet, until you start seriously scaling. I personally haven't have the same experience you've had with Mailchimp (that's what I use, and most emails land in recipients' inbox), but I would play around with other options and see which best suits you. Spinning up and managing your own email server seems a bit overkill for what sounds like something relatively early-stage.

Comment: Thanks for your response Carter, I think I need to experiment more on MailChimp as mine never goes to the primary inbox. Appreciate your help.